# html anchor tag reference

Tags: javascript, html

i have an anchor tag as below.

```
<a style="border:0px" href='javascript:deleteAttachment(this);' />
```

Inside the deleteAttachment, how can i get the anchor tag. Sending this to the method, sends the window element to the method.

```
function deleteAttachment(ancElement){
    //Jquery operation on acnElement
}
```

Please helop me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onclick` handler:

```
<a onclick="deleteAttachment(this)">
```

or, the cleanest and most accepted method nowadays, have just the raw link in the HTML:

```
<a id="deleteAttachment">
```

and add the click event programmatically, in a separate script block, on DOM load:

```
 document.getElementByID("deleteAttachment").onclick = 
    function() {  ... you can use "this" here ....  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a slightly different approach, since what you're trying to do is a bit old.
assuming you already loaded jQuery, here we go:

```
<a id="myFirstLink" href="someHref" />
<a class="otherLinks" href="secondHref" />
<a class="otherLinks" href="thirdHref" />

<script>
$(function() {
     $('#myFirstLink, .otherLinks').click( function(event) {
         // stops the browser from following the link like it would normally would
         event.preventDefault(); 
         // do something with your href value for example
         alert( $(this).attr('href') );
     });
});
</script>
```

So basically what you can do is this: simply generate all your anchors like you would normally would and apply the same class name to each of them - in my example the class would be "otherLinks".
After that, all your links will be handled by that anonymous function.

Comment: I did pointed out, quote: "assuming you already loaded jQuery, here we go"

Answer (score 1):

you must set its ID attribute

```
  <a id="myAnchor" style="border:0px;" href="javascript:deleteAttachment('myAnchor');"/>
```

then use jquery to find it

```
function deleteAttachment(ID)
{
   var MyAnchor =  $('#'+ID);
}
```

Comment: sorry i din elaborate the question properly.. the anchor tag was dynamically generated from asp.net gridview. so id(ClientID) is not in html's control. May be i can use javascript:deleteAttachment('<%= myAnchor.ClientID'); but onclick is easy to go for me.. Thanks for the answer.. :)